# Как ответить на ajax запрос на node.js сервере ( Без EXPRESS)

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Код на клиенте

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: '/load',
    success: function(data) {console.log(data)},
    error: function (error) {console.log(error)} 
});
```

Код на сервере

```
// готовим data (считываем текст из файла)
var data;
fs.readFile('./db/db.txt', function(err, logData){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err+' can not read file');
    }
    else{
        var text = logData.toString();
        var getElems = new Parser(text);
        data = JSON.stringify(getElems.data());
    }
});            
res.writeHead(200);
res.end(data);
```

В ajax запросе запускается success но в data ничего нету. Можно ли методом  res.end() отвечать на такой запрос, или нужно что либо другое. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Опять кто-то не понимает асинхронщину... доколе? .-. Короткий ответ: да, вы ошиблись, в `data` на момент ответа ничего нет.

Comment: D-side Если я правильно понимаю отправку данных нужно сделать в коллбэке функции readFile?

Comment: Предположительно -- да. Можно ещё насовать по коду `console.log`'ов, чтобы увидеть порядок выполнения кода и ключевые значения.